# Referencing a script provided by google (online) in my pages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, durandal

I am working on a Visual Studio C# solution with the Durandal template.

Usually I bundle my script files like this:

```
  bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/vendor")
      .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js")
      .Include("~/Scripts/knockout.validation.js")          
      .Include("~/Scripts/sammy-{version}.js")
          .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
              ... some more here ...
    );
```

Then at the starting of my app I call this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/vendor")
```

Now my problem is I have the following code provided by google online:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

I only need this script for one of my pages. And I think there is no sence to reference this in my bundles.

**How do I have to proceed?**

Simply keep this `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` code as is in my html page?

Any advises?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with keeping this in your bundle or directly in your view?

Answer (score 0):

I would measure if the time to load this script is significant and make a decision based on that. Normally, the initial index page is loaded once in Durandal's application life cycle and it can be done in a very user friendly way (Please wait message). This is then your google maps script can be loaded.

If you choose to load your script within view, you have to understand, that Durandal will exclude any script tag from html views other than index.cshtml. If you want to render script tags within views, you should use knockout custom bindings. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20590626/1449423) answer.